# Page becomes completely unclickable in firefoxdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium, and there are certain pages that are completely unclickable.  Let me explain.

If I go to a page using chrome or Firefox (not selenium), the page works perfectly.  However, once I go to the same page in FirefoxDriver, when I use click() or sendKeys(Keys.RETURN), it doesn't throw an error, it simply doesn't click on it.  Furthermore, while the browser is open, if I manually try clicking on elements, they don't work.

I have verified that there are no frames on the page that I have to navigate through.  I've tried clicking on buttons, links, other elements, and they all do the same thing.  On other pages, Selenium works fine.

I am unable to release the source of the page, but I can definitely answer questions about it.

Thank you!

EDIT: Here's the code I am doing, really basic:

driver.get(url);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".toolbar-logo")).click();

Comment: What versions of FF, Selenium, and OS are you using?  Can you show the selenium code you are trying to run?

Comment: FF17, Selenium 2.29.1, Win7.  Yes, I can...but I don't think it will make much difference.  Let me un-abstract it, and I'll edit my post

Comment: is it the same behavior when you do By.className("toolbar-logo")? Can you verify there is only one element that is of class "toolbar-logo"? Selenium might be trying to click on the wrong element.

Comment: Yes, same behavior.  It doesn't matter which element, or what kind of selector I use.  The thing that bugs me the most is that I can't click anything on the page (using my mouse) when its running.

Comment: We'll need to see a copy of the page to verify your problem.

Comment: I don't know what happened...but it just started working.  Thanks anyways.